# why does agent.add need to be "returned" from within a firestore query in dialogflow?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, dialogflow-es

I've got a function in dialogflow fulfilment that is called when an intent is matched.
it queries the firestore database. firstly, i don't quite get why the query itself needs the return keyword and also why agent.add needs to be returned. i'm assuming it has something to do with how promises work.

```
function one(agent) {

    let userRef = db.collection('users');
    let queryRef = userRef.where("uId", "==", "1");

    return queryRef.get().then(function(doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
            console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
            return agent.add(some info from the doc);
        } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
            return agent.add("error");
        }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });

}
```

One other thing I noticed that I don't quite get. If I have function one and function two and put the query in function two then it won't work.

```
function one(agent) {

    function two();

}

function two() {

    function one(agent) {

        let userRef = db.collection('users');
        let queryRef = userRef.where("uId", "==", "1");

        return queryRef.get().then(function(doc) {
            if (doc.exists) {
                console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
                return agent.add(some info from the doc);
            } else {
                // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
                console.log("No such document!");
                return agent.add("error");
            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run this code in DialogFlow it runs in Google's Cloud Functions environment. Google keeps the runtime for Cloud Functions available only as long as it's needed.

By default Cloud Functions stops the container when the final `}` of your code has run. But in your case the call to `queryRef.get()` happens asynchronously, so is still running by the time the `}` has executed. To prevent Cloud Functions from terminating your code before the database call is finished, you return the return value from `queryRef.get()` to Cloud Functions, which is a so-called promise.

When Cloud Functions gets a promise back from your code, it keeps the function alive until that promise completes. So by returning the promise from `queryRef.get()` your Cloud Functions environment will stay alive until the database call is completed.

In the same vein `agent.add` is an asynchronous call that writes a response to the calling agent. To prevent this call from being terminated prematurely by Cloud Functions, you also need to return the result from `agent.add` to Cloud Functions.

By the nature of promises, when you return a promise inside a `then()` that promise essentially bubbles up. So Cloud Functions ends up waiting until both the database query *and* the response writing have finished.

Comment: Thanks @frank. As a side note i've initialised a firebase project on my desktop which is the same project being used by dialogflow. If i deploy index.js from my desktop to cloud functions, i'm guessing it will prob overwrite the index.js from fulfilment?